# Private vs Public variables

Tags: c#, variables, private, public

```
namespace hi
{
    class hithere
    {
         public int numberOne = 12;
         public int numberTwo = 12;

         static void yo()
         {
             public int numberThree = 12;
             private int numberFour = 12;
         }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me the difference between the variables numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree and numberFour in this code excerpt?

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid C# code. IIRC you cannot put a public/private keyword before local variables. Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: This wouldn't compile by any stretch. `function yo` is completely invalid and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what is `function yo` supposed to be? The name suggests a function, but the absence of params and use of `public` and `private` suggest an inner class. The code snippet won't compile, its not really clear what you intended.

Comment: @user542169: Your code still isn't legal; local variables (variables declared within a function) can't be assigned a scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numberOne and numberTwo are public instance variables in heap.  They can be accessed directly inside of an object who has an instance of the hithere object.  numberThree and numberFour cannot be accessed this way as they are not instance variables and are encapsulated within the scope of the function yo and stored in it respective stack.

Comment: Wait, so can you access these from another class? I still don't understand the difference between a public and private variable, as with One and Two.

Comment: Pretend you're in another class... you can write this code:  

HiThere hiObj = new HiThere();
if(hiObj.numberOne==hiObj.numberTwo)

Comment: What bad usability, if you try to hit enter to insert a carriage return in this comment box it submits it automatically...  

man the comment box is a lot smaller than the answer box... You can access numberOne and numberTwo directly from an instance of a HiThere object.  (e.g. hiObj.numberOne; or hiObj.numberTwo;).  You can also access the static method directly as you would any other static method (e.g. HiThere.yo();).  I'd suggest reading up on encapsulation, static and instance variables/methods.

Answer (score 9):

numberOne and numberTwo are member variables of the class.
numberThree and numberFour are local variables, scoped to the function.
Next to that, you cannot declare an access modifier (private / public) for local variables.

Comment: Then, his question doesn't make sence.  Probably some kind of pseudo-c# code.